# How to unit test the methods of a class whose constructor take some arguments?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, constructor, phpunit

I have a class of form something like this:

```
class A{  
    public function __constructor(classB b , classC c){
    //
    }

    public function getSum(var1, var2){
        return var1+var2;
    }
}
```

My test case class is something like this:

```
use A;   
class ATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{  

    public function testGetSum{  
        $a = new A();
        $this->assertEquals(3, $a->getSum(1,2));  
    }  
}
```

However when I run the phpunit, it throws some error like:

`Missing argument 1 for \..\::__construct(), called in /../A.php on line 5`

Even if I provide the arguments, it throws the same error but in different file.
say, I instantiate by 
`$a = new A(new classB(), new classC());`

Then, I get the same error for the constructor of classB(the constructor of classB has similar form to that of A).

`Missing argument 1 for \..\::__construct(), called in /../B.php on line 10`

Is there any other way, I can test the function or something which I am missing.

I don't want to test by using mock (getMockBuilder(),setMethods(),getMock()) as it seems to defy the whole purpose of unit testing.

Comment: Try it with the setUp method of PHPUNIT

Comment: "Even if I provide the arguments, it throws error." It shouldn't. Creating an object inside a PHPunit class should be no different than creating it somewhere else. Your problem sounds like it is with the object's constructor itself, not PHPunit.

Comment: @WillemRenzema, I also feel the same. But unable to resolve it.

Comment: @sunil Your edit changes things considerably. I suspect Tomasz's answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea behind unit test it to test a class / method itself, not dependencies of this class. In order to unit test you class `A` you should not use real instances of your constructor arguments but use **mocks** instead. `PHPUnit` provides nice way to create ones, so:

```
use A;   
class ATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{  

    public function testGetSum{  
        $arg1Mock = $this->getMock('classB'); //use fully qualified class name
        $arg2Mock = $this->getMockBuilder('classC')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock(); //use mock builder in case classC constructor requires additional arguments
        $a = new A($arg1Mock, $arg2Mock);
        $this->assertEquals(3, $a->getSum(1,2));  
    }  
}
```

Note: If you won't be using mock's here but a real classB and classC instances it won't be unit test anymore - it will be a functional test

Comment: What if we need to mock a method in Class 'A' also, then can we do anything?

Answer (score 5):

You could tell to PHPUnit which method you want to mock of a specified class, with the methods `setMethods`. [From the doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html):

> `setMethods(array $methods)` can be called on the Mock Builder object
>   to specify the methods that are to be replaced with a configurable
>   test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed. If you
>   call `setMethods(null)`, then no methods will be replaced.

So you can construct your class without replacing any methods but bypass the construct as following (working) code:

```
public function testGetSum(){
    $a = $this->getMockBuilder(A::class)
        ->setMethods(null)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->assertEquals(3, $a->getSum(1,2));
}
```

Hope this help