# How to test correct call of constructor with PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Using PHPUnit, how can I properly test that the constructor (for class `Built` in the simplified example below) is being correctly called?  Class `Container` is the class being tested.  I want to be able to catch things like the intentional typo in the array key, below.  It's not possible to mock constructors, otherwise this would be straight forward.

```
class Container {
    public function create(string $input) {
        $request = new Built(["rid" => $input]); // Oops, typo in keyname.
    }
}
class Built {
    private $tid;
    public function __construct(array $params) {
        $this->tid = $params["tid"];
    }
}
```

This is a different situation from that described in [How to unit test the methods of a class whose constructor take some arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390074/how-to-unit-test-the-methods-of-a-class-whose-constructor-take-some-arguments), because my class under test is instantiating the second class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unit test the methods of a class whose constructor take some arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390074/how-to-unit-test-the-methods-of-a-class-whose-constructor-take-some-arguments)

Comment: No, it does not, because my class under test is instantiating a second class, rather than using an injected class.

Answer (score 4):

A constructor should not do any work other than 1) verify data passed to it and abort object construction with an exception when the data is rejected and 2) assign data passed to it to properties. Therefore the only thing that can and should be tested with regards to object construction is that invalid data is rejected and does not lead to the construction of an object that violates the contract of the class.